# How to create a login application using Google web tool kit?

Tags: gwt

I am new in gwt.I want to create a login application using google web tool kit.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides a short tutorial which describes how to create a login page with user/password authentication and storing the data in a server-side secure fashion: [google-web-toolkit-incubator Login Security FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ)